# How to call the function from user input?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, input

I'm trying to call `Floyd_Warshall(G)` from `user_command` however I get this `error`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 24, in <module>
Floyd_Warshall()
NameError: name 'Floyd_Warshall' is not defined
```

How to call it to get rid of this error?

```
import sys
import re

print("File containing graph: ")

while True:

   user_input = input()
   if user_input == "input1.txt":
      print("Possible Commands are:")
      print("dijkstra x - Runs Dijkstra starting at node X. X must be an integer")
      print("floyd - Runs Floyd's algorithm")
      print("help - prints this menu")
      print("exit or ctrl-D - Exits the program")
      print("Enter command: ")
      user_command = input()
      if user_command == "help":
         print("Possible Commands are:")
         print("dijkstra x - Runs Dijkstra starting at node X. X must be an integer")
         print("floyd - Runs Floyd's algorithm")
         print("help - prints this menu")
         print("exit or ctrl-D - Exits the program")
         elif user_command == "floyd":
         Floyd_Warshall()
      else:
         print ("dijkstra")
   elif user_input == "input2.txt":
      print("Possible Commands are:")
      print("dijkstra x - Runs Dijkstra starting at node X. X must be an integer")
      print("floyd - Runs Floyd's algorithm")
      print("help - prints this menu")
      print("exit or ctrl-D - Exits the program")
   elif user_input == "input3.txt":
      print("Possible Commands are:")
      print("dijkstra x - Runs Dijkstra starting at node X. X must be an integer")
      print("floyd - Runs Floyd's algorithm")
      print("help - prints this menu")
      print("exit or ctrl-D - Exits the program")
   elif user_input == "exit":
      sys.exit(0)
   else:
      print("Wrong choice")



def Floyd_Warshall(G):

............
............

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Floyd_Warshall()
```

Answer (score 0):

function should be defined before calling it. So place the function before while loop

```
import sys
import re

# also this function needs one input mandatorily
def Floyd_Warshall(G):

............
............


print("File containing graph: ")

while True:

   user_input = input()
   if user_input == "input1.txt":
      print("Possible Commands are:")
      print("dijkstra x - Runs Dijkstra starting at node X. X must be an integer")
      print("floyd - Runs Floyd's algorithm")
      print("help - prints this menu")
      print("exit or ctrl-D - Exits the program")
      print("Enter command: ")
      user_command = input()
      if user_command == "help":
         print("Possible Commands are:")
         print("dijkstra x - Runs Dijkstra starting at node X. X must be an integer")
         print("floyd - Runs Floyd's algorithm")
         print("help - prints this menu")
         print("exit or ctrl-D - Exits the program")
         elif user_command == "floyd":
         Floyd_Warshall()
      else:
         print ("dijkstra")
   elif user_input == "input2.txt":
      print("Possible Commands are:")
      print("dijkstra x - Runs Dijkstra starting at node X. X must be an integer")
      print("floyd - Runs Floyd's algorithm")
      print("help - prints this menu")
      print("exit or ctrl-D - Exits the program")
   elif user_input == "input3.txt":
      print("Possible Commands are:")
      print("dijkstra x - Runs Dijkstra starting at node X. X must be an integer")
      print("floyd - Runs Floyd's algorithm")
      print("help - prints this menu")
      print("exit or ctrl-D - Exits the program")
   elif user_input == "exit":
      sys.exit(0)
   else:
      print("Wrong choice")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Floyd_Warshall()
```

Answer (score 0):

Its would not run anyway:

```
Floyd_Warshall()
```

and

```
def Floyd_Warshall(G):
```

are not compatible. The function needs a variable input, which is missing when you call it with `Floyd_Warshall()`

Comment: if the answer works, please consider accepting it, you could also upvote.